# How to bind string in ChartJs in asp.net using C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to bind object to ChartJS datasets data but it's not appearing and there's no error.
Below is my C# Code:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static List<object> GetChartData()
    {
        List<object> chartData = new List<object>();
        List<string> labels = new List<string>();
        List<int> data = new List<int>();                       
        labels.Add("Completed jobs");
        data.Add(Convert.ToInt32(90));
        labels.Add("Current running jobs");
        data.Add(Convert.ToInt32(10));
        chartData.Add(labels.ToArray());
        chartData.Add(data.ToArray());
        return chartData;
    }
```

My Client side code:

```
  function OnSuccess_(reponse) {
        var aData = reponse.d;
        window.ubdChart = new Chart(t, {
            type: "pie",
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    hoverBorderColor: "#ffffff",                        
                    data: aData, // Bind int values here
                    backgroundColor: ["rgba(0,123,255,0.9)", "rgba(0,123,255,0.5)"]
                }],
                labels: ["Completed jobs", "Current running jobs"]  //Bind label values here
            },               
            }
        })
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working after changing the code as below.

```
 function OnSuccess_(reponse) {
        var aData = reponse.d;
        console.log(aData);
        window.ubdChart = new Chart(t, {
            type: "pie",
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    hoverBorderColor: "#ffffff",                        
                    data: aData[1], 
                    backgroundColor: ["rgba(0,123,255,0.9)", "rgba(0,123,255,0.5)"]
                }],
                labels: aData[0] 
            },
            options: {
                legend: {
                    position: "bottom",
                    labels: { padding: 25, boxWidth: 20 }
                }, cutoutPercentage: 0, tooltips: { custom: !1, mode: "index", position: "nearest" }
            }
        })
    };
```